# Is there a way to type <enter> instead of <return> on a Mac keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ascii

Even though Macs have only one keyboard key for it, there is a difference between <kbd>(carriage) return</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>. I need to type an <kbd>enter</kbd> (not <kbd>return</kbd>) into a field (it's a macro utility, and there's no ability to enter ASCII codes).

I know there used to be a way to do this (maybe it's because I used to have a keyboard with a numeric keyboard where the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key sent an enter command) but I don't have a full-sized keyboard anymore. On my MacBook Pro keyboard, the <kbd>return</kbd> key has an "enter" label, too (in smaller type above "return") and I thought I might be able to use a modifier key (<kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd>/<kbd>Command</kbd>/<kbd>Control</kbd>), but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you able to grab a full-size keyboard and plug it into the USB port?

Comment: Yes… but I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't involve any extra hardware. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: There's only just one key for them both if you use Apple's abbreviated keyboard, which is a horrible kludge anyway.  (Putting the [fn] key where [control] belongs is a crime against UX design, and a slap in the face of all terminal users!)  The full keyboard has two keys.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>?

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately, my GoldTouch ergo keyboard doesn't have a <kbd>Fn</kbd> key (maybe because it has all the physical function keys already).

Comment: You should try adding that to the question, as that changes what to suggest

Comment: Actually, my original question was framed in the context of _not_ having access to an external keyboard, so your answer is spot-on for the MBP keyboard. Thanks!!

Comment: Ahhh, OK, I understand now

Answer (score 2):

Besides Canadian Luke's correct answer above, I discovered a kinda kludgy way to do this as well, and it should work whatever keyboard (or lack thereof) you have. From the Input menu (enabled† by setting **Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar** in the **Keyboard** system preference), choose **Show Keyboard Viewer**.

Then, in the "virtual" keyboard palette, click <kbd>Fn</kbd>; you should see the icon on <kbd>Return</kbd> change to an icon looking roughly like a "K" turned 90°. That's the symbol/icon for <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

† For OS X versions earlier than Lion, the input menu is enabled by setting **Show input menu in menu bar** in the **Languages & Text** system preference) and then choosing **Show Keyboard Viewer**.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to for example map control-return to enter:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RETURN, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::ENTER</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```